# C/C++ and NMBGF write binary file get stamped with intel mark right before ENDF

Tags: c, intel, binaryfiles

I use parts of the NMGF library (downloaded from http://wasmerconsulting.com/nmgf.htm) to output griddata in NMBGF binary format. I use MSVS 2013 and have Intel Parallel Studio Cluster Edition 2016 installed.
I basically only use a few parts of the NMGF library to output sections and data to a binary file (using the following functions in NMBF library: `NMBGF_PutStandardSectionProlog` and `NMBGF_PutInteger`, as well as `NMBGF_CreateOutputContextAttachedToFile2`, `NMBGF_PutGRIDSection` and `NMBGF_EndWritingOutputFile`). Everything seems to work all right with writing the file. 
I only experience that right before

> ENDF

is put at the end of the file (happens in `NMBGF_EndWritingOutputFile`) the following characters are put as well

> n  t e l S W T o o l s \ T r a c e   A n a l y z e r   a n d   C o l l e c t o r

with various length (sometimes it lacks more characters then other times).
(I look at the content of the binary files using the built-in viewer (F3) in TotalCommander).

I cannot see anywhere in the NMGF library code that this would be part of the NMGF library, but I guess it has more to do with Intel Parallel Studio. Has anyone a clue about this?? (and how to avoid it?)

Comment: That *very likely* looks that advertised buffer size and initialized buffer size somewhere in your code differ. Or rather more like a pointer entirely gone astray. *What*'s at that pointer would be pure coincidence, I guess and rather not worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @tofro, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

@tofro was right, a pointer was pointing at a part of the grid that hadn't been set. Thanks a lot @tofro!